# Why is the UITypeEditor "DateTimeEditor" not visible in the object browser?

Tags: datetime, uitypeeditor

I'm writing a custom control *(using VS2010 & C#)* and it has a property which is a nullable datetime.

Why is it that, when defining my property, I can write this...

```
[Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.DateTimeEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public DateTime? When
{
    :
}
```

...but not this...

```
[Editor(typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.DateTimeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public DateTime? When
{
    :
}
```

Why is the DateTimeEditor not visible in the object browser *(for example)* ?

Thanks,
Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a reference to System.Design for the DatetimeEditor to be visibile in Object Browser.

Comment: Thanks. Initially, I couldn't add a reference to System.Design, but that was because my project was targetting ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile". Once changed to just .Net4 it worked fine.